# How to increase the quality of image after capture by using Xamarin camera?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have followed the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaizJhx-FVg to activate the camera function, but after I capture the image, its quality becomes very low. Any idea on how the quality of an image could be adjusted?

This is the camera function code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace Interactive_Ringgit_Recognizer_Try
{
    [Activity(Label = "Interactive_Ringgit_Recognizer", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        ImageView imageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var btnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
            imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

            btnCamera.Click += BtnCamera_Click;
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode,[GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent         (Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to increase the quality of image after capture by using Xamarin camera?

When you take a photo from camera, you could create a directory to save the photo in, by creating a file and adding its Uri to the intent, the camera application will save the resulting photo in this file.

```
public static class App {
    public static Java.IO.File _file;
    public static Java.IO.File _dir;     
    public static Bitmap bitmap;
}

private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(App._file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

In the `OnActivityResult` method, we make the photo available in the device image gallery. Then you could call a helper method to resize the image to display.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Make it available in the gallery
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(App._file);
    mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
    SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display
    // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory 
    // and cause the application to crash.

    int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    int width = _imageView.Height;
    App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
    if (App.bitmap != null)
    {
        _imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);
        App.bitmap = null;
    }

    // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
    GC.Collect();
}
```

The `LoadAndResizeBitmap` method :

```
public static Bitmap LoadAndResizeBitmap(this string fileName, int width, int height)
{
    // First we get the dimensions of the file on disk
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
    BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);

    // Next we calculate the ratio that we need to resize the image by
    // in order to fit the requested dimensions.
    int outHeight = options.OutHeight;
    int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (outHeight > height || outWidth > width)
    {
        inSampleSize = outWidth > outHeight
                           ? outHeight / height
                           : outWidth / width;
    }

    // Now we will load the image and have BitmapFactory resize it for us.
    options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

For the complete code, you could refer to this [official document](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/).

Comment: Hi , the photo is cant in gallery
, any ideas where is the gallery?

Comment: What's you mean "cant in a gallery"? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: sorry typo, the image fail to store in gallery

Comment: Have you added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest file?

Comment: Have you tested the official sample? Did it work on your device?

Comment: First, make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your device, you could see it in Settings -> Apps -> yourapppackagename -> Permissions -> Storage. Second, when you use the official sample to capture a picture, is the picture displayed in the `ImageView`?